# Multiple conditions for string variable

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-conditions

I am trying to add a new column "profile_type" to a dataframe "df_new" which contains the string **"Decision Maker"** if the "job_title" has any one of the following words: (Head or VP or COO or CEO or CMO or CLO or Chief or Partner or Founder or Owner or CIO or CTO or President or Leaders),

**"Key Influencer"** if the "job_title" has any one of the following words:  (Senior or Consultant or Manager or Learning or Training or Talent or HR or Human Resources or Consultant or L&D or Lead), and

**"Influencer"** for all other fields in "job_title".

For example, if the 'job_title' includes a row "Learning and Development Specialist", the code has to pull out just the word 'Learning' and segregate it as 'Key Influencer' under 'profile_type'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. As such, "Any help is highly appreciated." is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and "Thanks in advance." is [not wanted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160). "I've tried with if-else statements, but returns nothing" We can only possibly comment on attempts **that are actually shown to us**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

```
import re
s1 = pd.Series(df['job_title'])

condition1 = s1.str.contains('Director|Head|VP|COO|CEO...', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)

condition2 = s1.str.contains('Senior|Consultant|Manager|Learning...', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)

df_new['profile_type'] = np.where(condition1 == True, 'Decision Maker', 
         (np.where(condition2 == True, 'Key Influencer', 'Influencer')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

dm_titles = ['Head', 'VP', 'COO', ...]
ki_titles = ['Senior ', 'Consultant', 'Manager', ...]


conditions = [
(any([word in  new_df['job_title'] for word in dm_titles])),
(any([word in  new_df['job_title'] for word in ki_titles])),
(all([word not in  new_df['job_title'] for word in dm_titles] + [word not in  new_df['job_title'] for word in ki_titles]))
]

values = ["Decision Maker", "Key Influencer", "Influencer"]

df_new['profile_type'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: Thank you @Hobanator. 
I tried the code that you suggested, However, it returns only 'Influencer'. 

For example, if the 'job_title' includes a row "Learning and Development Specialist", the code has to pull out just the word 'Learning' and segregate it as 'Key Influencer' under 'profile_type'.

Comment: The edited code is returning only 'Influencer'.

Answer (score -1):

First, define a function that acts on a row of the dataframe, and returns what you want: in your case, `'Decision Maker'` if the `job_title` contains any words in your list.

```
def is_key_worker(row):
    if (row["job_title"] == "CTO" or row["job_title"]=="Founder") # add more here.
```

Next, apply the function to your dataframe, along axis 1.

```
df_new["Key influencer"] = df_new.apply(is_key_worker, axis=1)
```

Comment: For example,  if the 'job_title' includes a row "Learning and Development Specialist", the code has to pull out just the word 'Learning' and segregate it as 'Key Influencer' under 'profile_type'.

Comment: I would suggest reading the comment made on your answer, on how to ask a good question.